# SQL Find closest timestmaps when duplicates exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I cant find topic to my problem, so i'm asking here.
I have select:

```
  SELECT t1.*, 
         t2.unixtimestamp as rj_time, 
         t2.response_detail as rj_error 
    FROM t1
         LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 
              ON t1.id=t2.personid 
              AND t1.clientcode=t2.client
   WHERE t1.clientcode='quouk' 
         AND (t1.language = 'en_GB') 
ORDER BY t1.id
```

TABLE 1:

```
id     clientcode     language     
 1      quouk          en_GB
 2      quouk          en_GB
 3      quouk          en_GB
```

TABLE 2:

```
id     personid     client     language     unixtimestamp     response_detail     
 1      1            quouk      en_GB        1393401000       error
 2      1            quouk      en_GB        1393401001       error
 3      2            quouk      en_GB        1393404600       error
 4      2            quouk      en_GB        1393404601       error
 5      3            quouk      en_GB        1393257900       error 
 6      3            quouk      en_GB        1393257901       error
```

So if i am launching this query, it returning to me 6 rows, but the result should be 3 rows (from table 2 : 2, 4, 6 id's). If you will look into timestamps you will see a small difference between rows. That means i need to find closest dates to now. I saw a lot of solutions to use `LIMIT` at the end of the query, but i think it is a bit different in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*, MAX(t2.unixtimestamp as rj_time), t2.response_detail as rj_error 
FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id=t2.personid AND t1.clientcode=t2.client
WHERE t1.clientcode='quouk' 
  AND (t1.language = 'en_GB') 
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the timestamps are not in the future then the nearest one to now will be the latest one.

As such you can probably do this by adding a simple LEFT JOIN against a sub query:-

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.unixtimestamp as rj_time, t2.response_detail as rj_error 
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT personid, client, MAX(unixtimestamp) AS MaxTimeStamp
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY personid, clientcode
) Sub1
ON t1.id = Sub1.personid AND t1.clientcode = Sub1.client
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 as t2 
ON Sub1.personid=t2.personid AND Sub1.client = t2.client AND Sub1.MaxTimeStamp = t2.unixtimestamp
WHERE t1.clientcode='quouk' 
AND (t1.language = 'en_GB') 
ORDER BY t1.id
```

This gets the latest timestamp for each person / client from table2, and then joins that against table2 to get the other columns that are required (ie response_detail). If you just used MAX then you would possibly not get the correct value of response_detail as that would come from an undefined row rather than from the row that the MAX applies to.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. @StanislavL offered a bit simplier, just select max timestamp, and group by ID, that worker perferctly. Thanks.

Comment: Afraid his solution will not work consistently due to the need to return t2.response_detail. As that column is not listed in the GROUP BY clause MySQL does not know which value of that column to return from the rows for a person / client. It might be from the same row as the max timestamp but this is not certain. Which one it returns is undefined. The manual pages probably explain this better - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: @Kickstart I agree that my response is not perfect. The table in the Q don't have the field. But yours has a leak as well Sub1.MaxTimeStamp = t2.unixtimestamp won't work if there are multiple records with the same time=MAX +1 anyway

Comment: @StanislavL - agree on that potential issue but in that case the OP has not specified which row they would like returned or if such a situation is possible. If that is possible then I suspect we would have to use the id to guess which is the latest of the 2 records with the same timestamp, adding another sub query.